# python query dict object doesn't return value for the key

Tags: python, django

in my view

```
 request.GET
```

returns queryDict object as follows-

```
 <QueryDict: {u'{"title":"title","description":"description"}': [u'']}>
```

i want to get the values of title and description

this is what i tried as per the doc

```
request.GET['title']
request.GET.__getitem__('title')
```

but none of them seems to be working for me,it just stops the execution; what am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it to a python dictionary and then access the elements:

```
a = dict(request.GET.iterlists())

>>> print a['title']
title
```

Answer (score 2):

The data that is being passed in looks like JSON, rather than form-encoded parameters. You should probably access it directly and unserialize it:

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
```

Comment: thanks @Daniel Roseman; yes you are right the data i am passing is from ajax- like {title:'title',description:'desc'}, but how do i pass the data so that i can access it as i pointed in a question.

Comment: I don't know because you haven't posted the Ajax call. But what's wrong with doing it like I show here? It's just one additional call, now you can access `data['title']`, and you don't need to modify your Javascript.

Comment: no probs, just curious - thanks for that answer it works perfectly;